# Hide activity on button click with shared preferences, android studio

Tags: android

How can I use shared preference in android studio to achieve this?

On my app, Splash Screen redirects to Activity A.

There is a button on Activity A, When this button on Activity A is clicked, next time when user opens app, Activity A will not show again, Activity B must open next.

The logic here is, Activity A is my welcome screen, after user clicks get started on this activity, I don't want this Activity to open again. Activity B is my Main Activity

NB: I have checked all questions and answers on stackoverflow, they did not help, the ones available where showing activity only on first run and this not a duplicate question, any help provided is appreciated.

Comment: What problems did you run into using shared preferences? Other answer on SO are more than correct and they apply to your requirement; that it's not something new to SO, therefore it's your logic/code that is the problem.

Comment: The logic is different from the ones on SO, they may be working for their purpose but not mine, if you have a link to any question on SO that solves this, that will help. Literally the solutions I have seen is to set welcome screen to show only on app first run, but I want welcome screen to keep showing until button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store boolean by shared preference to do that. Here your AcitivityA class.

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    try {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean firsttimeLoad = prefs.getBoolean("first_time_load", true);
        if (!firsttimeLoad) {
            sendToB();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("first_time_load", false);
            editor.commit();
            sendToB();
        }
    });

}

private void sendToB() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}}
```

Comment: This answer is great but it's not what I wish to achieve, with this Activity A will disappear after first run, I want To redirect to Activity B when  button on Activity A is clicked, technically I hope it's possible

Comment: You said that "There is a button on Activity A, When this button on Activity A is clicked, next time when user opens app, Activity A will not show again, Activity B must open next." . Follow answer and You can add that code on Button onClickListener()--     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first_time_load", false);
        editor.commit();

Comment: I tried it, the code is on called when that button is clicked, meaning it still brings me back to welcome screen on every run, when button is clicked ,that is when it checks for first or no first run and decide where next to redirect to

Comment: Words will not be enough to appreciate you, it takes only a smart developer to figure this technique , thank you, this solved my problem like magic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code im using for save the sigin details from firebase you can check this out and try this

```
      private fun handleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?) {
        try {
            if (task!!.isSuccessful) {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                PreferenceHelper.writeBooleanToPreference(KEY_LOGIN_WITH_OAUTH, true)
                updatePreference(account!!)
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("UserName", account.displayName)
                intent.putExtra("UserEmail", account.email)
                intent.putExtra("UserPhoto", account.photoUrl?.toString())
                intent.putExtra("uid", account.id)
                saveUser(account)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Login Error " + task.exception?.message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }

    private fun updatePreference(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        PreferenceHelper.writeBooleanToPreference(KEY_USER_LOGGED_IN, true)
        PreferenceHelper.writeStringToPreference(KEY_USER_GOOGLE_ID, account.id)
        PreferenceHelper.writeStringToPreference(
            KEY_DISPLAY_NAME,
            account.displayName
        )
        PreferenceHelper.writeStringToPreference(
            KEY_USER_GOOGLE_GMAIL,
            account.email
        )
    }
```

Comment: This should work, but in my case no sign in, just want the splahscreen to always redirect to welcome screen, then when accept button on welcome screen is clicked splash screen should then redirect to main activity on every run

Comment: You just need to just add wirtebooleantopreference true and pass the data if you want to

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects the button on Activity A, add a value to the shared preferences. What the value is does not really matter. Every time your app is launched, check if this value exists in the shared preferences, if it does launch Activity B, if it doesn't, launch Activiy A.

In `onCreate` of Activity A

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (sharedPref.contains("notFirstLaunch")) {
    // Launch Activity B
}

Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notFirstLaunch", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a code instance of this suggestion, I will be grateful

Comment: I have added some example code, hope this helps :)

Comment: This solution is wonderful, one thing, the code on the button onclick listener, says "Cannot resolve symbol 'SharedPref' why is this so, do I need to add any variable below import or....

Comment: You may need to redefine `sharedPref` in the onclick listener or check that the spelling is exactly the same